# Create a general "skeleton" from a c# project

Tags: c#, architecture, analysis

I've a very complex solution in c# containing about 20 projects, each of them control a device since it is a driver.

In many cases those projects use similar structures/code (for example everyone as a connect method, a retrive data method and so on).

Is there a tool to analyze the code and create a general "Skeleton" that can be reused?

Comment: that tool is your brain ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily create a project template from an existing project from the `File>Export Template` menu. The process is described in [How To: Create Project Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28VS.ExportTemplateWizard%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version=v4.5%29&rd=true).

There is no tool that can decide what to include in a skeleton project, as this depends on knowledge of what each project actually does, which parts that can be generalized and which have to be project specific.

You can use duplicate analysis in Visual Studio or Resharper to find repeated code, but this won't tell you what should be in a template and what shouldn't.

What you can do, is:

1. Extract common functionality in a separate project that all device projects will reference
2. Create a template from one of the device projects.
3. Use template parameters to [customize the resulting template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185311.aspx).

Step #1 will result in a much simpler template, that is easier to customize